# C.moveToFirst always returns false in android using SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am using below query for fetching data from sqlite database:

```
SELECT  * FROM CASHIER Where Type = 1 And DATE Between '2014/03/31' And '2014/04/06';
```

It shows accurate result in SQLite Administrator but when I use it in android `C.moveToFirst` returns `false` always.

Please anybody tell me why it's happening?

Below is my method:

```
public List<Income> getWeeklyIncomeRecords(String in_startWeek, String on_endWeek)
    {
        List<Globals.Income> income = new ArrayList<Globals.Income>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME1+" Where Type = 1" + " And DATE Between " +"'"+in_startWeek+"'"+ " And " +"'"+on_endWeek+"'";

        //Log.e(TAG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Globals globals = new Globals();
                Income td = globals.new Income();
                td.setIn_amount(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(AMOUNT))));
                td.setIn_catagory(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CATEGORY)));
                td.setIn_date((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DATE))));
                td.setIn_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NAME)));
                td.setIn_imagename(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(IMAGENAME)));
                income.add(td);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

         return income;         



    }
```

Comment: Question title says - `C.moveToFirst always returns null` whereas the question body says - `C.moveToFirst returns false always`. Which one of it is correct?

Comment: Post your whole function so that we can see where you define C

Comment: Please show some code: how do you perform the query?

Comment: @nikis : hey I added my method please take a look at it. . please.

Comment: The query matches no data. Is the database really the same as in your SQLite Administrator as you claim?

Answer (score 0):

Date type use format YYYY-MM-DD, so the query must be:

```
SELECT  * FROM CASHIER Where Type = 1 And DATE Between '2014-03-31' And '2014-04-06';
```

Comment: I checked it. . using the same Date type YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: "DATE" is a DATE or DATETIME?

Comment: It's a DATE. I used c.getCount() even but it is showing 0. I don't know why it's happening because as I earlier said, it's working perfectly in SQLite Administrator.

Answer (score -2):

Replace

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

by

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: Please explain why that would help (hint: it doesn't)